Issues during setting STM32 environment in Clion
Apologies in advance for any novice inquiries, as I'm relatively new to embedded development. I've been attempting to utilize CLion for writing and debugging programs on STM32 chips. Despite investing considerable time in troubleshooting various issues, I find myself at an impasse. Here's what I've done so far: I've installed the latest version of CLion (2024), Arm GNU Toolchain 13.2, and Open On-Chip Debugger from this GitHub repository (https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/OpenOD). However, I'm encountering errors upon downloading the program to my device.
Any guidance on resolving this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!
Clion console feedback:
/usr/local/bin/openocd -s /usr/local/share/openocd/scripts -f board/stm32l476g-disco.cfg -c "tcl_port disabled" -c "gdb_port disabled" -c "tcl_port disabled" -c "program \"/home/michal/Documents/STM32_files/clion_test04/cmake-build-debug/clion_test04.elf\"" -c reset -c shutdown
Open On-Chip Debugger 0.12.0-00024-g34afaa939 (2024-04-18-14:40) [https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/OpenOCD]
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
Info : The selected transport took over low-level target control. The results might differ compared to plain JTAG/SWD
Info : clock speed 500 kHz
Info : STLINK V2J43M28 (API v2) VID:PID 0483:374B
Info : Target voltage: 3.252984
Info : [stm32l4x.cpu] Cortex-M4 r0p1 processor detected
Info : [stm32l4x.cpu] target has 6 breakpoints, 4 watchpoints
Info : gdb port disabled
Info : Unable to match requested speed 500 kHz, using 480 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 500 kHz, using 480 kHz
[stm32l4x.cpu] halted due to debug-request, current mode: Thread 
xPSR: 0x01000000 pc: 0x08000330 msp: 0x20018000
** Programming Started **
Info : device idcode = 0x10076415 (STM32L47/L48xx - Rev 4 : 0x1007)
Info : RDP level 0 (0xAA)
Info : flash size = 1024 KiB
Info : flash mode : dual-bank
Info : Padding image section 1 at 0x080012c4 with 4 bytes (bank write end alignment)
Warn : Adding extra erase range, 0x080012c8 .. 0x080017ff
** Programming Finished **
Info : Unable to match requested speed 500 kHz, using 480 kHz
Info : Unable to match requested speed 500 kHz, using 480 kHz
shutdown command invoked


Make sure that you are using correct cfg file. Sometimes it doesn't work because of that. What is your STM32 board?
